# Custom overlay around a div using css - Custom handle for jQuery resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Hi i am using jquery resizable, rotatable()  [https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable@1.1/jquery.ui.rotatable.min.js] in my project .

So when this function called i get handles to rotate and resize the div.

```js
$( function() {

        var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("user_file");
        inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);

        function previewImages(){
            var fileList = this.files;

            var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
                  var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
                  $('.new-multiple').append('<div class="img-div"><img src="' + objectUrl + '" class="newly-added" /></div>');
                  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
                }

        $( ".img-div" ).draggable();
       $('.img-div').rotatable();
        $( ".img-div" ).resizable({aspectRatio:true});
              $(".newly-added").on("click", function(e) {
    $(".newly-added").removeClass("img-selected");
       $(this).addClass("img-selected");
     e.stopPropagation()
    });

   $(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is(".newly-added") === false) {
    $(".newly-added").removeClass("img-selected");
  }
   });
              
              } 
});
```

```css
.new-multiple{
  width:400px !important;
  height:400px !important;
  background:white;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
  
  
 .img-div{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
 } 
 .newly-added{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
} 

.img-selected{
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px 6px rgb(206, 206, 206);
  border:2px solid rgb(145, 44, 94);
}
.ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-se.ui-icon.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid tomato;
}
.ui-rotatable-handle.ui-draggable {
    background-color: white !important;
    border: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable@1.1/jquery.ui.rotatable.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable@1.1/jquery.ui.rotatable.min.js"></script>
<input   name="user_file[]" id="user_file" style="position: relative;overflow: hidden" multiple="" type="file">

 <div class="new-multiple"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vd11qyzv/21/

So when i am uploading a image i get control handles like this

[image]

But i want to place custom control handle like this

[image]

How can i achieve this using css and jquery. Please help

Comment: You might want to start here: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles As I have mentioned in your previous posts, there are lots of resources available if you look. Even examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `handles` option in resizable, you can then manage them with CSS. Their style and location.

**CSS Snippet**

```
.ui-resizable-handle {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00CCff;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}

.ui-resizable-nw {
  top: -7px;
  left: -7px;
}

.ui-resizable-ne {
  top: -7px;
  right: -7px;
}

.ui-resizable-e {
  top: calc(50% - 7px);
  right: -7px;
}

.ui-resizable-w {
  top: calc(50% - 7px);
  left: -7px;
}

.ui-resizable-sw {
  bottom: -7px;
  left: -7px;
}

.ui-resizable-se {
  right: -7px;
  bottom: -7px;
}

.ui-resizable-se.ui-icon {
  display: none;
}

.ui-rotatable-handle {
  background-size: 14px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00CCff;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 9px);
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var inputLocalFont = $("#user_file");
  inputLocalFont.change(previewImages);

  function previewImages() {
    var fileList = this.files;
    var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
      var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
      var $newDiv = $("<div>", {
        class: "img-div"
      });
      var $newImg = $("<img>", {
        src: objectUrl,
        class: "newly-added"
      }).appendTo($newDiv);
      $(".new-multiple").append($newDiv);
      $newDiv.draggable();
      $newDiv.rotatable();
      $newDiv.resizable({
        aspectRatio: true,
        handles: "ne, nw, e, se, sw, w"
      });
      $newDiv.find(".ui-icon").removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se");
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
    }
    $(".newly-added").on("click", function(e) {
      $(".newly-added").removeClass("img-selected");
      $(this).addClass("img-selected");
      e.stopPropagation()
    });

    $(document).on("click", function(e) {
      if ($(e.target).is(".newly-added") === false) {
        $(".newly-added").removeClass("img-selected");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/s99kxydw/

Comment: really thank you friend . You are brilliant . How can you achieve this much fast ?